# CentOS: Error accessing yum.conf

Tags: linux, centos, java

While attempting to [install Java on CentOS 6.9](http://devopspy.com/linux/install-java-8-on-centos-rhel-7/), I encountered an error:

> CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config
>   file:///etc/yum.conf

I've found a few similar threads, but none of the advice is applicable.

After doing a little research, I've discovered the following:

Running `yum -version` gives me the same error.

Running `whereis yum` gives me:

> yum: /usr/bin/yum /usr/share/man/man8/yum.8.gz

Running `rpm -qf /etc/yum.conf` gives me:

> yum-3.2.29-81.el6.centos.noarch

Yum isn't to be found at: `/etc/yum/`

At this point, I have no idea if Yum is installed or not, or broken or not.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear which command is used to install `java`, as the link is dead. It's also not clear whether user got a `sudo` access.